# Rep bug: +2 x 3 = +4?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I was looking at [someone's rep](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/98/raphael?tab=reputation) (cs private beta) and noticed an anomaly. I expanded a post with "2 events" and "+4" rep, only to find three (3) events, each with +2 rep.

[image: unexpanded]

[image: expanded]

This user did hit the rep cap in the day in question, but if my math is correct, he got credit for 200 between edits and upvotes, as he should have, and 15 for someone else accepting his answer, as he should have, for 215. He also accepted two questions, each noted as +2, but as  his total rep for the day stands at 217, it appears he only got credit for one of these.

Comment: They're doing all kinds of funky stuff with the reputation history right now.

Comment: @animuson I know, I'm just making sure they know of this so they can fix it.

Comment: Uhhhhhhhhh, yeah that shouldn't happen, will take a look in the morning.

Comment: Looks to me like 88 points.

Comment: @jo8691 If only it were that easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just outside your screenshot the +2 was listed for the accepted, the suggested edits were being rolled up but not with the accept...but the ajax call to get the details didn't care and showed all 3 for the post.

Starting with the next build, these will be properly rolled up into a +6.

Comment: Aha, guess I missed that the post titles for the "2" accepted answers were the same.  Thanks for figuring that out so quick. [But why are you working this late?]

Comment: @Kevin - Had to fix another critical bug, missing `)` in a query that was pushed, heading off to bed now :)